# How can I remove external IP address that errored while creating it in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

Some external IP addresses I tried to create errored out while creating. If I go to VPC Network > External IP Addresses in Google Cloud Platform, I have two entries for external IP addresses with a red exclamation point that I can't delete. How can I get rid of them? When I hover over the red exclamation point, it says: "At most one access config currently supported."

I also have a notification that says:
The request contains invalid arguments: "At most one access config currently supported.". Error code: "badRequest"

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zobnl.png)

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your page? With the IP address masked, of course.

Comment: Sure, I edited my original post. See above.

Comment: Very strange... Static without IP reserved, no version (IPv4 of IPv6),... I think the support can help you on this. An internal bug of the platform I guess

Comment: Is there no other way without contacting support? I don't have a paid support subscription.

Comment: Of course, you have a public issue tracker, without SLA on the response time: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Have you tried using gcloud commands to [list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/addresses/list) and/or [delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/addresses/delete)?

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/161297289) was identified and solved few months ago, it looks like it was an issue with the Cloud Console (GUI), as suggested in the comments, to discard or confirm an issue with the GUI run the equivalent gcloud (or applicable) command, for example:

> gcloud compute addresses list

In this case, if the IP addresses are not listed in the output, then most likely there is an error with the Cloud Console, please report this or any other issue with the Cloud Consle directly in [this component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187225&template=0) or check the entire [component list](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) if necessary.